# AppPool running ASP.NET app under IIS 10 randomly stops processing requests

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a peculiar problem that exhibits itself sporadically - i.e. it happens maybe once a day, or even just once every couple of days - seemingly at random. I've determined it's not a hard crash, because that would leave an entry along with the call stack in the system event log. Which it doesn't.

It does however leave a warning saying:

`A process serving application pool 'XYZ' failed to respond to a ping.`

Which is just a consequence of IIS's worker process health check.

So far, I've been able to catch the w3wp process once while it was left hanging in this state for a minute or so. I've observed that it had an unusually high CPU load. It was doing *something*, but nothing useful. It wasn't accepting nor handling any new requests, nor did it log any events on its own (which should normally happen on a dedicated thread every 10 seconds or so).

It simply looked as if all of the threads were busy doing nothing, akin to burning CPU via an endless while loop.

I finally had to recycle the pool, which spun off a new instance of the app in a new w3wp process, as expected. What surprised me was that the old process kept running until I killed it manually via Task Manager.

I have no idea how an ASP.NET app could possibly get itself into such a state.

The only possibility I'm aware of is if there was a bug within the app's async code, which somehow managed to produce an endless async loop. To my understanding, this wouldn't cause a StackOverflowException, because threads get switched on each async continuation. But it would (could?) suffocate the thread pool, eventually causing it to run out of free threads and essentially stop the process from responding to any stimuli. At least, that is my current hypothesis.

But how would I confirm this? There's an enormous amount of code involved and we have no reliably repeatable case so far. What would be the best place to start untangling this?

Comment: if the app connects to something external like a DB or other service, I would investigate that first, something in common with all requests of your app - maybe that is having issues. If not, then you're just going to have go through the code - try to connect to it with the IDE debugger when it's in that state.

Comment: "It simply looked as if all of the threads were busy doing nothing, akin to burning CPU via an endless while loop" is the issue, but honestly not everyone can easily tell what's wrong from a glance (years of experience is required). Hire a consultant or open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com, and you might get the help you wanted. Make no guess please, as you can enter the wrong paths and waste your time there.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, and there is no specific cause for this. so you can try to debug the cause using IIS [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @NickAbbot: Your comment made me think! I then went and added some ConfigureAwait(false) calls to awaited tasks in places where external network calls are being made. We're observing the app now to see if it made any change.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for posterity...

It seems that the culprit was lack of `ConfigureAwait(false)` calls on certain paths that involve communication with PostgreSql database, specifically. The app in question also communicates with Firebird and RavenDB, but those paths were not affected.

At present, it is not clear what change prompted this sudden requirement after years of having worked just fine without the need for `ConfigureAwait(false)` calls in these same paths...

Nothing really stood out during analysis of the code commits.

I will continue to observe and try to determine the cause. However, for now, things seem to be working, finally. I will post an update, if anything changes or if new evidence comes to light!